# dlib import failure on M1 pro

Tags: python, pycharm, apple-m1, dlib

after installing dlib successfully on my m1 pro mac (monterey 12.1)
[image]

whenever I try to import dlib, I am receiving the following error:

```
     from _dlib_pybind11 import *
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ImportError: 
dlopen(path/to/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_dlib_pybind11.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/path/to/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_dlib_pybind11.cpython-310-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/_dlib_pybind11.cpython-310-darwin.so' (no such file)
```

Comment: Have you tried googling the error? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/421486/m1-mac-mini-python-reports-mach-o-but-wrong-architecture Sounds like it might not be installing for the architecture you have. There are a number of thoughts around what to do there (although, personally the answers seem underwhelming to me). YMMV. This was just the first google result though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

installing dlib==19.23.0 solves this issue

Comment: Thank you. This also solve my issue from M1 pro. 

>>> import dlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dlib/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from _dlib_pybind11 import *
ImportError: dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_dlib_pybind11.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_png_do_expand_palette_rgb8_neon'

Comment: It also solve problem on M2

Comment: It does not work.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
Failed to build dlib
ERROR: Could not build wheels for dlib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects